# Create 2 dimensional array from 1 dimensional

Tags: php

How from this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [BLACK] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3171
                    [1] => 3173
                    [2] => 3175
                )

            [WHITE] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3170
                    [1] => 3172
                    [2] => 3174
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [SMALL] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3170
                    [1] => 3171
                )

            [MEDIUM] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3172
                    [1] => 3173
                )

            [LARGE] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3174
                    [1] => 3175
                )

        )

)
```

I could create something like this:

```
$array['BLACK']['SMALL'] = 3171;
$array['BLACK']['MEDIUM'] = 3173;
$array['BLACK']['LARGE'] = 3175;

$array['WHITE']['SMALL'] = 3170;
$array['WHITE']['MEDIUM'] = 3172;
$array['WHITE']['LARGE'] = 3174;
```

so create 2 dimensional array from 1 dimensional, where option is same.

Comment: what you have tried so far.

Comment: Are BLACK, SMALL, MEDIUM etc constants? If not you are missing quotes.

Comment: What's really interesting is where this array comes from, and can't you reorganize the source instead. )

Comment: Also you are confused about dimensions of an array. There is nothing 1 dimensional in the examples above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$colors = array('BLACK' => array('3171','3173','3175'),'WHITE' => array('3170','3172','3174'));
$sizes = array('SMALL' => array('3170','3171'),'MEDIUM' => array('3172','3173'), 'LARGE' => array('3174','3175'));

$merged = array();
foreach ($colors as $c_key => $color) {
foreach ($color as $c_val) {
    foreach ($sizes as $s_key => $size) {
    foreach ($size as $s_val) {
        if  ($c_val == $s_val) {
            $merged[$c_key][$s_key] = $c_val;       
        }
    }
    }
}
}
// var_dump($merged);
?>
```